# Storing Objects inside Object in Arrays in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic2, javascript-objects

I'm trying to store this data, given from a Wordpress Backend with HTTP Get Request in Ionic 2 (Angular 2).

I'm receiving this data structure,

Console Log of data response-

[image]

I'm trying to store this data like the menus (menu_1 and menu_2) in array of menus, the categories in array of categories, dishes in array of dishes...

How can I do that?

I don't want to show or iterate using Pipes, I only want to storage in Arrays to work easier with them.

My code at the moment is like:

home.ts:

I have a injectable class (Globals) to call the http get, but I do the subscribe in the getMenus function on my home.ts component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Globals } from '../../providers/globals';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  providers: [Globals],
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  menus: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public globals: Globals) {
    this.getMenus();
  }

  getMenus() {
    this.globals.getMenus().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.menus = data;
      },
      err => { console.log(err) }
    );
  }
}
```

And I have created a class, called Menu, at the moment is very simple:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class Menu {
  name: any;
  categories: any;

  constructor() {
    this.name = this.name;
    this.categories = this.categories;
  }
}
```

Where name is basic field of the object (key: name, value: "Today's menu" and categories is cat_1, cat_2 (two objects inside menu_1 object, which each contains more objects (dish_1, dish_2...).

My idea is create a class for every one of them, class Menu, class Category and class Dish. But I have any idea of how can I start store this objects in this classes. :S

Greetings!

Comment: "I'm trying to store this data" - trying how? Add the code you have to your question

Comment: I've tried many things, but none have worked. Maybe it's more correct saying "I want" instead to "I'm trying"...

Comment: So you should include what you've tried in your question. You should include the code that you have, and anything else that will make your question easier to answer.

Comment: Nitzan, I added my code, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to create an interface for the data that you receive from the server, something like:

```
interface Dish {
      Name: string;
      Description: string;
      Thumbnail: string;
}

interface Category {
      [name: string]: Dish;
}

type ServerResponse = {
      [name: string]: { [name: string]: Category; } & { name: string };
}
```

If you want to create classes from this data you can then:

```
class Menu {
      name: string;
      categories: { [name: string]: Category };

      constructor(data: { [name: string]: Category; } & { name: string }) {
            this.name = data.name;
            this.categories = {};

            Object.keys(data).forEach(name => {
                  if (name !== "name") {
                        this.categories[name] = new Category(data[name]);
                  }
            });
      }
}

(data: ServerResponse) => {
      this.menus = {};
      Object.keys(data).forEach(name => {
            this.menus[name] = new Menu(data[name]);
      });
}
```

You should also create the `Category` class and all, but that's the idea.

Comment: Nice answer! I'm newbie on Typescript, but I'm trying to do that. One more question... How I can implement this in typescript?

type ServerResponse = {
      [name: string]: { [name: string]: Category; } & { name: string };
}

Ionic 2 throw me this error: "A class may only implement another class or interface."

Comment: What are you trying to do which results in that error? That line by itself is fine with the compiler, are you trying to extend `ServerResponse`?

Comment: Yes, now I've created the class Menu, Category, Dish and the file data-services.ts with those three interfaces, I'm trying to implement ServerResponse in the class where I have the suscribe to http request. Is that incorrect?

Comment: There's no need to implement `ServerResponse`, or any of the other interfaces I posted, the json data object that you receive from the server already matches those interfaces, you only need to cast to that.

Comment: Hi Nitzan, sorry for my late response, I've been trying your method, but it doesn't work to me, probably because my inexperience.

I have the classes structure created now, but I don't know how to storage the json into his respective classes (menu in menus, categories in categories...)

  getMenus(): any {
    return this.http.get(this.rul)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map(res => deserialize<Menu[]>(Menu, res));
  }

I'm using serializer.ts (https://www.npmjs.com/package/serializer.ts) to deserialize data. Is that correct?

Greetings.

Comment: I've never worked with `serializer.ts` so I can't help you on that one..

Comment: Ok, i'm back to your way. I copied all exactly as you said. Ionic throws me error:

Argument of type 'Menu' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [name: string]: Category; } & { name: string; }'. Type 'Menu' is not assignable to type '{ [name: string]: Category; }'. Index signature is missing in type 'Menu'.

Comment: You need to have `this.menus` as `{ [name: string]: Menu }`, and not `ServerResponse`. That type only represents the data you get back from the server, but from that date you want to create `Menu` instances.

Comment: Hi Nitzan, good news. It finally works! Your answer was amazing.

I have been delayed because of my limited knowledge of Typescript, but I have finally succeeded and it helped to me to learn!

Thank you very much. ;)

Answer (score 0):

## What are you trying to do ?

I think what you're trying to do is to ***normalize*** your data.

(Are you using a Redux pattern ? Maybe Ngrx ? If so, this is a great idea to normalize !)

Here's how a normalized state looks like : http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

## How should you do it ?

You can either do it by hand, which will become quite hard if you have many other requests to deal with, or you can describe your data in [***schema***](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#schema) and use [***normalizr***](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) to do this job (normalizing data) for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know where to start. You can try this approach. First, create a model:

```
export class DummyModel {
 menu: any;
 cat: any;
 dish: any;
 ...
//you can replace any with the type expected (string, number, etc)
}
```

In your component, you import your dummyModel and you set the data

```
import { DummyModel }                from '../dummy.model';
/...
dummyModel: DummyModel = dummyData;
```

Also, consider @Nitzan Tomer advise, try to write your code and people here can help if you are facing an issue

Comment: Yes. This is more or less what I want.

Data returns me an Object that contains other objects, and in the class "Menu" I only want to save the field "name" in name variable and categories (but only the key, which is the name: "cat_1" and "cat_2", because the value is the entire object which contains the dishes).

I do not know if I'm explaining well, sorry if my doubt is very confusing.